# How can I remove the -mthumb compiler flag in XCode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uikit

I've been reading that by default there is an -mthumb compiler flag which reduces code size by 35%. However, in a floating-point calculation intensive app like mine, this is not an good option, like apple says. I'd like to try it out if it changes anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for "thumb" in the target options and uncheck the box.

Or follow [**these instructions**](http://blog.sapusmedia.com/2008/12/compile-for-thumb.html) on **blog.sapusmedia.com**.